# Search result issue with Search API module

Tags: search

I'm working with `Drupal-7`; where i have installed so many different modules in it. one of them modules is `"Search API"`.

The problem what i'm facing is Result of searched keyword. whenever i use to search for a particular keyword it working for the Exact match with that key word.

**For example :**  `keyword = "Drupal" ;` 
then result only retrieved if this exact word will match with the content of database. but i would like to get result which are having any of these characters.

**For example :** `keyword = "Dru" ;` 
then also all the result will retrieved which is having only word `"Dru"` as well as `"Drupal"`  & etc..

In short now Query is working with `"="` operator but i would like to make it with `"LIKE"` operator.

**What should i do in which page to get resolve this..?**

I have tried to many things but not get success.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Apache Solr in the back-end, then you will have to use the [Fuzzy Search](http://drupal.org/project/fuzzysearch) module in conjunction with the Search API module. This module provides drupal sites with a fuzzy search engine to allow for broader keyword matches including partial or misspelled keywords.

*Note: At time of writing this there is some incompatibility with Search API 7.x-1.0-rc1 and Fuzzy Search 7.x-1.x-dev (2011-May-12). To get these two working together, you will need to use the search_api 7.x-1.0-beta10 until the Fuzzy Search maintainer gets the module caught up to the current release of Search API.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using the [Porter-Stemmer](http://drupal.org/project/porterstemmer) module, even though it doesn't exactly allow searching for partial words: It tries to reduce words to their root words. If, for example, you look for *walking*, the search will return any page containing *walk*, *walks*, *walking*, or *walked*, whose stem word is *walk*. It doesn't allow to search for *walking* using *king* as search string.

If you were using Apache Solr as search back-end, searching for partial matching would be implemented in Apache Solr.